# Is Synchronized(keyword) still working fine when the method is not invoked in a Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, plsql, synchronization

I am wondering if a method will be still synchronized, if a method is called not in a Java thread but from an another language like PL/SQL.

As far as I am concerned, plsql does not have thread ,but it has session, what if I hope that the method being called from plsql procedure can be synchronized,is the behavior the same as being called in a Java Thread.

In my test ,I add a code call Thread.sleep(5000) in the Java synchronized(keyword) method,which will be called in the plsql procedures, and log for the time after this sleep as well as log the thread id.

Surprise to see that the BOTH Thread id are 1! And also, the time where they pass the sleep() are in the same time(seconds). Why is that?

My question is

1.Does the synchronized keyword still work fine in the java method, it seems that it is not.

2 Does this calling create a java Thread.

3.Does the synchronized keyword or other Java concurrency object like(Semaphore,conditionObject) only is only working in a Java Thread?

Comment: If there is only one thread in PL/SQL, which doesn't seem likely, you don't have any need for synchronization at all, but if there are, synchronization must work, by definition. It isn't clear what exactly you're asking here.

Comment: @EJP: I think it is not unlikely at all. Every Oracle connection usually gets its own server process. So maybe every connection also gets their own JVM (with effectively just one user thread in it), and you need some inter-process locking for synchronization to work.

Comment: If code is running, it is in a Thread.  synchronized works when used correctly, and it doesn't start a thread unless you call Thread.start(). You are right that you have to have a thread to use any class.